# "less than" - wrong understanding or mistake?

Tags: meaning

As English is not my mother tongue, I am not sure whether I really do not understand the text below or if there is a mistake with "<" and ">" (less than, more than). Shouldn't it say "...were eligible for the intervention trial if >80% of prescribed doses were taken"? Otherwise the whole text doesn't make any sense, right?

[a scientific text http://www.easteregg.ch/lessthan.jpg](http://www.easteregg.ch/lessthan.jpg)

Comment: Impossible to tell without more context; but if the “intervention trial” and the “study” refer to the same thing, I would agree that it’s a typo and it should be one _<_ and one _>_. Which one goes in which sentence depends on the further context, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is based on the **adherence details**:  If the patient took less that 80% but also did so **within the 2 week time period**, they were eligible for the trial study but if they just took less than 80%, and **not specifically within the 2 week time window**, they were not eligible for the study.

Drug trial protocol **not only requires adherence but timely use of the drug being tested** -This was an elimination produce